# For the main image on the landing page, can a dark contrasting background help increase conversion?

Tags: color-theory, contrast, focus

**BACKGROUND OF PROJECT**
Initially I envisioned that the header would have an image that can span the entire width of the page. I was thinking centered, and it would be so wide that as you stretched it, you would see more but it would blur progressively outward.

However without having a photographer to shoot that with a better set and models I only have the current image to work with. And here is what I have created so far.

*disregard the items on the top bar which are in progress

[image: Version 1]

**CURRENT OBSERVATIONS**
My thought process when I created this current example was that a dark background would force visual focus to the image. The models are then redirecting you with their eyes to the message and call-to-action.

I was wondering what your experiences have been or if maybe I should go with a different color.

Comment: Definitely a ux.se question.

Comment: @Scott- So I am wondering perhaps how to rephrase this. My intent was to get the graphics to look better. I guess the part where I discuss conversion makes it more UX, but the question still centers around the execution of the graphics.

Answer (score 1):

While we, and more likely ux.stackexchange, could give you reasonably accurate judgements if your question was something more on the lines of "Will having the user click through three pages before checking out instead of two affect my conversions?", a question based this subjectively on the aesthetic of not even the website in general, rather a single landing page, can only be answered by your analytics data after testing it out. Prior to that, your guess is as good as ours assuming you have two equally professional, clean, and trustworthy designs to choose from.

As far as stretching the banner, it depends on your photoshop skills, but I think you could probably have the sides fade into that blurry greenish blue, maybe add a subtle abstract patter to the edgest, and scale the image down 30%-50%, and simply have a very large banner which spans the page. Inface, it may look cleaner as is to give this a white background and do as I suggested with blurring the edges into a color fitting the image.

Comment: Ok I will try the "blurring the edges into a color fitting the image"